# A proposition on an irreducible polynomial over a non-archimedean field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Suppose $K$ is a non-archimedean complete field(i.e. a field with a non-archimedean valuation). Let $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_{i} x^{i} \in K[x]$ and suppose $f(x)$ is irreducible. How to prove  $\max \left\{\left|a_{i}\right|\right\}=\max \left\{\left|a_{0}\right|,\left|a_{k}\right|\right\}$ ?

Comment: Wlog assume that $a_n=1$, $f = \prod_{j=1}^n (x-b_j)$, then the claim follows from that $|b_j|=|b_1|$, considering the two cases $|b_1|\le 1$ and $|b_1|>1$.

Comment: @reuns Thanks you very much!